# How to create a vertical gradient in flex

Tags: css, apache-flex, actionscript-3

How to create vertical gradient in flex.

What i currently have is a horizontal color gradient. And its working fine. But I am unable to figure out how should I make it vertical (which ofcourse is the requirement)

I use styleName = "chatWindowLeftGradient"

```
<mx:VBox id="chatTabBarVBox" height="100%" styleName="chatWindowLeftGradient">

</mx:VBox>
```

And the style sheet looks like this:

```
<mx:Style>
        .chatWindowLeftGradient{                        
            backgroundImage: ClassReference("custom.GradientBackground");
            backgroundSize: "100%";
            fillColors: #6db263, #a4d9a1;
            fillAlphas: 1, 1;                           
        }

    </mx:Style>
```

This give a gradient from top to bottom. How i can make from left to right??

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flex 3, the easiest way to apply a gradient to an element is to use Degrafa and its excellent CSSSkin class. Some good examples of its flexibility are here: [Nice and Easy Gradients with CSSSkin](http://www.flexstuff.co.uk/2009/04/14/degrafa-nice-and-easy-gradients-with-cssskin/)

Answer (score 3):

This won't just plug into your css, but a vertical gradient in Flex 4 mxml looks like this:

```
<s:Rect right="0" top="0" width="170" bottom="0">
    <s:fill>
        <mx:LinearGradient rotation="90">
            <mx:entries>
                <mx:GradientEntry color="#64574A"/>
                <mx:GradientEntry color="#FFFFCC"/>
            </mx:entries>
        </mx:LinearGradient>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

Have you tried adding a rotation="90" to your style?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a programmatic skin.

1. Create a new class that inherits from Border.
2. Override updateDisplayList with something like this:

   super.updateDisplayList(w,h);
   var g:Graphics = this.graphics;

   g.clear();

   var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
   m.createGradientBox(w,h);
   g.lineStyle(0,0,0);
   g.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR,[color1,color2], [alpha1,alpha2], [0,0xFF],m);
   g.drawRect(0,0,w,h);
   g.endFill();
3. Reference this class as your skin using the ClassReference in the style section.